# Make !important the whole .class selector

Tags: css

Is it possible to make the entire .class CSS selector important? I'm thinking in this kind of structure:

```
.custom-selector !important {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `!important` is thought to be an instrument of last resort and as such should be used sparingly. `!important`ing whole selectors would caricature that idea.

If you need to trump other styles, use [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to your advantage. You can use, e.g., these techniques to push your style declarations to the top:

- double class name will trump single class name:

  `.custom-selector.custom-selector > .custom-selector`
- ID trumps class:

  `#custom-id > .custom-class`
- IDs can be duplicated, too:

  `#id#id > #id`
- inline styles trump any stylesheets:

  ```
  <style>
  p#id#id.class.class { color: green; }
  </style>
  <p id="id" class="class" style="color:red">I am red!</p>
  ```

*New feature since 2023:* CSS now has a feature called “layers”. You can define them like this:

```css
@layer base {
  h1 {
    color: green;
  }
}
@layer higher {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}
h1 {
  color: purple;
}
```

The result is a purple `<h1>`. Um, ... “yay!”? Doesn’t sound too useful when you first encounter it. `@layer` styles are always *less* important than “unlayered” styles. This sounds like the absolute opposite of what was asked.

But if you start to get the hang of it, `@layer`s make a lot of sense. Tailwind [uses them, too](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer), for example, and you can import styles from unsupporting frameworks into your own layers:

```css
@import url(bootstrap.css) layer(bootstrap);
```

This allows you to structure your CSS from least to most important and overwrite styles in lower layers without resorting to `!important` or selector trickery.

Comment: that last sentence got me lol. Perfect. I need to go write sensible CSS, rather than looking to cut corners

Comment: The libraries we use do not write sensible CSS extremely often. Sometimes, we need to !important the styles, and sometimes we don't. This is a failure in foresight of the designers of CSS to not expect this to happen, to expect developers to be in control of the CSS they are working with. 

Answer (score 7):

First off !important applies to one specific declaration in a CSS rule. It doesn't apply to a class. So, "no" you can't make a class !important.

Second off, !important is just one part of CSS specificity. You can also use other ways to make a rule be a more specific rule to have precedence (such as referring to an id in the parent chain instead of just the class. When I'm writing CSS, using !important is my last possible choice - I'd much rather solve overrides with other specificity solutions. Usually, if you control all the CSS, this is pretty easy to avoid using !important. If you have to override some CSS that you don't control, then sometimes it is handy.

Check [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501658/can-an-entire-css-class-have-its-specificity-as-important) for more details. As it explains things better.